# Where can I find a comprehensive list of valid methods for a given Google Apps Services Class?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I’m having trouble finding documentation that lists all of the methods for a given Class.

For example, `getName()` is a valid method for the SpreadsheetApp class, but [it’s not listed in its methods in the class documentation.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Where can I find a comprehensive list of valid methods for this Class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Apps Script reference is very comprehensive.

I think in your case you are confusing the `Spreadsheet` class and the `SpreadsheetApp` class.
`SpreadsheetApp.getName()` does not work, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName()` does work and is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getName()).

SpreadsheetApp is the overall class containing everything to interact with a Spreadsheet including the Spreadsheet class, the Range class, etc. but also means to create and open spreadsheets.

An object of type Spreadsheet is an actual instance of a spreadsheet; that instance has a name and sheets and so on.